# Regular Expression Pattern \K Alternatives in PHP

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string

I've been using `\K` quite a lot but recently realized that it does not work in PHP below v5.2.4. So I'm looking for a different way.

```
<?php
    $html = '<div>hello</div>
        <div class="someclass">hi</div>
        <div class="sample">this text should be included</div>
        <div>bye</div>
    ';
    // $pattern = '/<div.+class=["\']sample["\'].+div>\K/i'; // <-- this doesn't work below v5.2.4
    $pattern = '/(?<=<div.+class=["\']sample["\'].+div>)/i'; // causes an error.
    $array = preg_split($pattern, $html);
    print_r($array);
?>
```

I've seen somewhere `(?<=)` can be used as the alternative and I tried it but it causes an error. Any suggestion?

Comment: `(?<=PAT)` doesn't work if `PAT` can match strings of varying width.

Comment: `$pattern = '/(<div.+class=["\']sample["\'].+div>)\${1}/i';` seems to work. The guy who answered it seems to have deleted his post. I thank him and wonder why he deleted it.

Comment: It was me. My answer was specific to substitution, and didn't apply to splitting. I'm happy it helped you anyway :) Go ahead and answer your own question if you want.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks again. On the other hand, as I keep testing, the above pattern does not produce exact the same result as `\K`. It includes the text, `<div>bye</div>` as well on contrary to `\K` which includes up to `<div class="sample">this text should be included</div>`. Any suggestion?

Comment: No, that's why I removed my answer. I'd re-implement `split` (using the equivalent of `while (/\G((?s:.*?)...)/g)`), but I don't know PHP at all.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It really helped and I combined your approach with another workaround and it seems to suit my need. I answered it by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found a workaround. `preg_split()` accepts the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag in the fourth parameter so the matching string can be included in the delimited elements of array. I just need to pick one additional element to extract the strings and it is not that much work to do.

```
<?php
    $html = '<div>hello</div>
        <div class="someclass">hi</div>
        <div class="sample">this text should be included</div>
        <div>bye</div>
    ';
    $pattern = '/(<div.+class=["\']sample["\'].+div>)\${0}/i'; 
    $array = preg_split($pattern, $html, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    print_r($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd re-implement `split`. It would look like the following in Perl:

```
my @matches;
while (/\G((?s:.*?)...)/gc) {
   push @matches, $1;
}

push @matches, /\G(.+)\z/sg;
```